# How to transform from a discrete to integral equation?

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics, discrete, models, adhesion

In this picture, the red curve is an elastic rod that has resistance to bending and extension. I am trying to model the adhesions (contact) between the rod and the substrate (glass): the green dashed lines. We will try to model it as in a spring-like bond. But, I need it in integral form.

From a numerical view, I can write that:
\begin{equation}
E = \sum_i \frac{1}{2}kz_i^2
\end{equation}
where $i$ represent the bond at certain position.

How can I transform this discretization into an integral form that covers all the green parts?

[[image: In this picture, at a certain position <span class=]$x$ adhesions start to appear" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrBqK.png)

Comment: Do you know what z is as a function of x?  If you only have the zs as a discrete set of points there's not much more you can do than some sort of summation.

Comment: How large are the steps $\Delta x$ between subsequent values of $z_i$ ?